# ImageVIew slightly outside of the parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I would like to have an imageview that should be half outside of the view. I have tried with the negative margin. But couldn't get the desired output. The image is getting cut off by the parent layout. Not sure what is the proper way to achieve the desired output. Any guidance would be appreciated.

**My Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".Activities.ProfileActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/drawer_background"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**This is target output**
[image: Target]

**This is my output**

[image: my output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `layout_anchor` for the `CoordinatorLayout` children
your xml file need be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialup.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ​

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/materialup.profile_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@color/black"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/materialup.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        />

    ​

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the result

[image: anchored image]

check this link on github for more reading

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorExamples